# Can anyone prove why inverse of $ST$ is $T^{-1}S^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-transformations

Can anyone please prove why this is ?

I think If you let $T^{-1}S^{-1}$ be inverse of $ST$

and consider $$ST(T^{-1}S^{-1}) = S(TT^{-1})S^{-1}  = S(I)S^{-1}$$ something like that.

But, Can anyone prove this without multiplying $ST$ by inverse of it?

$S$ and $T$ are functions domains in $V$ and Values in $V$

Comment: "Can anyone prove this without multiplying ST by inverse of it?" Not really. The definition of inverse is "multiply it by the original, and you get the identity". Kinda hard to skirt around the multiplication. Also, keep in mind that even if $(ST)^{-1}$ exists, $S^{-1}$ and $T^{-1}$ might not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you know that Linear operators/transformations on $V$ form a group denoted by $L(V)$ or $End(V)$, then it is just proving like if $a$ and $b$ are elements of a group $G$, then $(ab)^{-1}=(b)^{-1}(a)^{-1}$, Let $x$ be $(ab)^{-1}$, then $x(ab)=(ab)x=e$ which implies $b^{-1}=xa$ and $a^{-1}=bx$, from both of these you are getting $x=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.